# DataFrame String data Manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I've a csv file with data like the ones below and the data is arranged like x1,y1 in the first line and x2, y2 in the second line and again x1,y1 then x2,y2 and so on.

```
0.0            0.0          
2.500000E-03   0.0          
5.000000E-03   0.0          
7.500000E-03   0.0          
1.000000E-02   2.721289E-05 
1.250000E-02   6.772091E-04 
1.500000E-02   3.154052E-03 
1.750000E-02   7.072636E-03 
2.000000E-02   9.175906E-03 
2.250000E-02   8.454774E-03
```

And the output should be a text file in the x1, y1, x2, y2 format with some additional formatting like shown below. (astrix at the start and end and additional spaces)

```
*           0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00    2.500000E-03    0.000000E+00*
*           5.000000E-03    0.000000E+00    7.500000E-03    0.000000E+00*
*           1.000000E-02    2.721289E-05    1.250000E-02    6.772091E-04*
*           1.500000E-02    3.154052E-03    1.750000E-02    7.072636E-03*
*           2.000000E-02    9.175906E-03    2.250000E-02    8.454774E-03*
```

I tried with the below code and got the output but the zeroes are being written as 0.0 instead of the exponential 8 digits and also I'm thinking this could be done in a simpler way. please let me know if there is any other possible solution.

```
df_rfile = pd.DataFrame(r_file)
df_temp = df_rfile[0].str.split(" ", n=1, expand=True)
df_temp[1] = df_temp[1].str.strip()

df_odd = df_temp[::2]
df_odd.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df_even = df_temp[1::2]
df_even.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

df_final = pd.concat([df_odd, df_even], axis=1)
dfasString = df_final.to_string(header=False, index=False)

for eachline in dfasString.splitlines():
    x = eachline.split()
    modified_str = '*'+x[0].rjust(23,' ')+x[1].rjust(16,' ')+x[2].rjust(16,' ')+x[3].rjust(16,' ')+'*'
    final_out.write(modified_str+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = pd.read_csv(your_file.csv).to_numpy()

x1y1 = A[1::2] # select odd
x2y2 = A[::2] # select even
A = np.concatenate((x1y1, x2y2), axis=1) # concatenate
```

worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).